# Prometheus sum get no data , can i set to default value?

Tags: export, snmp, prometheus

i am trying to sum network traffic in/out from different IDC, also using `snmp_export` to get those information, but sometimes the snmp export can't get some switch's infomations ,maybe timeout or lost. so there is no date update for this switch and "/metric" will only show parts traffic info. The problem is when i using

```
sum(irate(ifInOctets{ifIndex=...,instance=...})) + 
sum(irate(ifInOctets{ifIndex=...,instance=...}))+ 
sum(irate(ifInOctets{ifIndex=...,instance=...}))
```

to get all traffic total value , the expr will return no data and break the graph.

I am newbie to prometheus. not sure if the using method is wrong .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to approach this is to use `rate()` with a long enough range to tolerate a failed scrape. For example if you are scraping once a minute then 5m is enough so you would use `sum without(instance) (rate(ifInOctects[5m]))`